# How to convert/migrate DateProperty to DateTimeProperty

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I know the difference between DateProperty and DateTimeProperty

[difference between DateProperty and DateTimeProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15550178/1175496)

I also appreciate how I could maintain my Schema (particularly missing values for properties) with tasks

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2019882/1175496

But I have a Model with `date_filed=db.DateProperty`
I find I almost always want the (time) accuracy of `db.DateTimeProperty` *How can I convert* this field from `DateTime` to `DateTimeProperty`?

My questions are:

- How to do it

  - ie simply change from `date_filed=db.DateProperty` to `date_filed=db.DateTimeProperty`
- Will it somehow update existing entities automatically?

  - ie or must I create a task to change them?
- If entities with have different types for same properties, how does filtering and ordering on that property work?

  - ie DateProperty to a datetime.datetime value
  - ie

> When a query involves a property with values of mixed types, the
>   Datastore uses a deterministic ordering based on the internal
>   representations: ...
>
> 2. Fixed-point numbers
>
>    - Integers
>    - Dates and times

- What are some outcomes / pitfalls

  - ie Validation Errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experimented with the simplest option, anticipated in the question. Also anticipated by the db.Model designers, it would seem (i.e. easy to do!)

- How to do it

  - **Yes:** simply change from date_filed=db.DateProperty to date_filed=db.DateTimeProperty
- Will it somehow update existing entities automatically?

  - **Kind of**: Specifically `DateProperty.get_value_for_datastore` method actually converts any `datetime.date` object to a `datetime.datetime` object before storing it as a "raw value" in the database.
  - Existing entities aren't really *updated automatically*, they just start using `DateTimeProperty.make_value_from_datastore`, (the opposite of `get_value_for_datastore`) which falls back to `Property.make_value_from_datastore`, which returns the raw value; the `datetime.datetime` object; not "truncating" it to a `datetime.date` object
  - **No need to** : ...create a task to change them
- If entities with have different types for same properties, how does filtering and ordering on that property work?

  - **Irrelevant in this case**; they have the same underlying type.
  - Although the "deterministic ordering based on internal representations" statement, which lists dates and datetimes both at the same bullet, suggests they have a common internal representation so they're comparable for ordering/filtering, etc.
- What are some outcomes / pitfalls

  - **None encountered** in this case; maybe someone has stories of other datatype migrations/conversions?

Comment: Nice summary.  When converting some types where the new type will cause a validation error, I have fetched the underlying datastore object and not used the Model.  This means you are just working with a dictionary.  What sort of approach (bulk update vs lazy updating) will depend on how much interruption will be caused during the migration and if your model can deal with the different types.

Comment: @TimHoffman, how do you fetch the underlying datastore object and not use the Model?

Comment: Have a look at this question, I provide code to do it in the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842671/migrating-data-when-changing-an-ndb-fields-property-type/19848970#19848970